# Redmine add new QueryColumn on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

What I have is a new column in the issue list that works very well.

**init.rb**

```
require 'redmine'

Redmine::Plugin.register :test do
   # ...
end

Issue.include IssuePatch
IssueQuery.include IssueQueryPatch
```

**issue_query_patch.rb**

```
module IssueQueryPatch
  def self.included(base)    
    base.class_eval do

      # TODO : add restriction
      self.available_columns << QueryColumn.new(
                                  :calcul_something,
                                  :caption => :Something
                                ))
      end
  end
end
```

**issue_patch.rb**
require_dependency 'issue'

```
module IssuePatch
  def self.included(base)
    def calcul_something
      return some_data
    end
  end
end
```

The issue I'm facing is that I want only some users (admin for example) be able to see that new column BUT in **init.rb** the current user is not already loaded and is anonymous so I cannot check its status.

In the official [Redmine Github](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/issue_query.rb), you can see that `User.current` is used.

Do I have to make my patches modules to be loaded later so that the user is loaded (how is it even possible and how to do that) or is there a trick ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using a `before_*` callback `before_validation` ([see ActiveRecord::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)).

Like :
What I have is a new column in the issue list that works very well.

**issue_query_patch.rb**

```
require_dependency 'issue_query'

module IssueQueryPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_validation :display_test

      def display_test
        if User.current.admin? || User.current.allowed_to?(:view_test, nil, :global => true)
          self.available_columns << QueryColumn.new(
                              :calcul_something,
                              :caption => :Something
                            ))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where `view_test` is a permission in **init.rb**.